# Cross saving between android and Pc PPSSPP

Tags: android, psp

I'm planing on playing FF Type 0 using my PC and phone, is there any way to transfer the saves and save states? Can it be done automatically using my wifi connection or do I need to hook my phone to the PC every time?

Comment: PPSSPP doesn't have such an option. On the PC with OneDrive you could create a junction from your documents folder to your OneDrive folder, not sure about Dropbox. The junction will allow PPSSPP to access OneDrive without being aware of it (it will still think it's accessing your `C:\Users\[USERNAME]\Documents\PPSSPP\PSP\SAVEDATA` folder). Not sure about Android, though. You might want to ask the [android.se]. As for how to make a junction on Windows, that's a question for [su]. You'll need `cmd.exe` and the `mklink` command. Try `mklink /?` to find out how to use `mklink`.

Comment: Before making junctions you might want to try manually copying over a file to see if the save files are compatible. It's not particularly likely that they are.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently doing this with syncthing. Works perfectly well.
Two notes:
Save games for Gran Turismo and little big planet won't load on a different psp than the one they were created on, but they load in ppsspp perfectly well. You should have no issues using them across PC and Android.
On Android 8 and above, syncthing won't be able to save data to the sd card, except if you use a subfolder inside the app folder. Since you can't change the save game folder in Android PPSSPP, you won't be able to sync if you use the sd card.